# Restricting directed paths on a Cactus Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I want to find the longest path distance on a [cactus graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph) with certain restricting directed paths.

For example, if we have following 4 nodes,
[image]

This would mean that

- if we visit 1, we cannot go to 2 **anymore**

That is, 1 → 2 and 1 → 3 → 2 are not allowed.
However, 2 → 1 is allowed.

Likewise

- cannot travel from 2 to 3
- cannot travel from 3 to 1
- cannot travel from 1 to 0
- can travel any others

So we have the probable paths (1, 3, 2), (0, 2, 1), and so on. Therefore the longest distance is 3, and we never get 4.

[image]

In this case, the answer is 9. (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9, 2, 3), etc...

I’m stuck on this problem one week. Still, I have no idea how to approach. Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the restrictions a bit?

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of [Blocking directed paths on a Cactus Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63821481/blocking-directed-paths-on-a-cactus-graph). Instead of duplicating a closed question, please improve the original so that it can be reopened and answered.

Answer (score 1):

Observation 1: there exists a path* on a set of nodes if and only if that set induces a subgraph with no cycles. Proof: if there is a cycle, then we cannot visit all of the nodes of the cycle, because the last one visited is forbidden by the node preceding it in the cycle. If there is no cycle, then reverse all of the arcs in the subgraph and find a topological order.

Observation 2: this problem is equivalent to the classical NP-hard problem [minimum feedback vertex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set), which asks for the smallest set of nodes whose deletion eliminates all cycles.

There are efficient algorithms for feedback vertex set in cactus graphs claimed, e.g., [Das (2012)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.682.7940&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

* Path seems to be defined in a nonstandard way for this question, as a sequence of nodes with no repetitions such that for each arc in the graph, the head of the arc does not appear after the tail. This is the definition that accords with the solution to the example graph, (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9, 2, 3), which has multiple consecutive vertices not connected by an arc.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your observation #2? I can see that you can reduce the first problem into the second one. What about the reverse?

Comment: @ciamej Hmm, it's pretty much by definition? I edited Observation 1 slightly to make it more obvious.

Comment: Hmm, minimum feedback vertex set asks for the smallest set of nodes whose deletion eliminates all cycles, then within such an acyclic graph we can find the longest path, *but* the path may not cover all vertexes of that graph. On the other hand we may remove a different set of vertexes (not the smallest one), to obtain a different acyclic graph with less vertexes but with a longer path. Or can't we? If not, why? It's not obvious to me...

Comment: @ciamej Ah, the notion of "path" here is nonstandard, going by the example answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem with the "path". How is your solution meant to work with a classic path notion? Consider an example of a directed graph with digit 8 shape (a central node connects two loops). By minimum feedback vertex set we have to remove the central node to eliminate all cycles. We end up with two disjoint cut loops. The longest path will be in the remains of one of the loops. But we can do better! Instead, we remove two neighbours of the central node, each one from a different loop, to get an S shaped graph. Now the path may span the entire graph.

Comment: @ciamej The question gives (4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 9, 2, 3) as a valid solution for the graph shown even though several of the consecutive vertices are not connected by an arc.

Comment: Ah, ok. I haven't analyzed the more complex example. Still, I think your solution is not correct even with regular paths, unless I misunderstood something.